# Caching LINQ-SQL objects and DataContext thread safety

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, thread-safety

We are querying database using LINQ-SQL and then storing resulting master table objects in HTTP cache.
Later, the master objects are being used to query its children, using lazy loading. Here are the relevant pieces of code - I have recreated the scenario in a new proof-of-concept app:

```
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["c"] == null)
        {
            LockApp.Models.DBDataContext db = new Models.DBDataContext();

            var master = db.Masters.ToList();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("c", master,
                    null, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 
                    TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

        }

        ViewBag.Data = (List<LockApp.Models.Master>)HttpRuntime.Cache["c"];
```

And here's the razor view that is iterating over master and detail objects:

```
    @foreach(var m in ViewBag.Data){
        @m.Id<nbsp></nbsp>
        foreach(var d in m.Details){
            @d.Id<nbsp></nbsp>
        }
        <br />
    }
```

It works perfectly fine and caches the data correctly. However, it fails when there are multiple requests trying to hit the web site after cache is cleared - I am testing this using JMeter, basically hitting the site with many (50) parallel threads, and then touching web.config - I immediately start seeing one of the following two errors:

**Index was outside the bounds of the array**

at foreach(var d in m.Details)

this error never goes away, i.e. some data gets corrupted in cache

with following stack:

```
  System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item) +34
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +305
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +59
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +118
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.CompiledQuery.Execute(IProvider provider, Object[] arguments) +99
   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSourceFactory`1.ExecuteKeyQuery(Object[] keyValues) +402
   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute(Object instance) +888
   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSource.GetEnumerator() +51
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load() +107
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.GetEnumerator() +13
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +4
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\prc0092\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LockApp\LockApp\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:16
```

or this error

**ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.**

at the same line foreach(var d in m.Details)

this error does go away after a while if I stop hitting the site with parallel requests

with following stack

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method) +5316460
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command) +7
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async) +155
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean asyncWrite) +82
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +1306
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +118
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.CompiledQuery.Execute(IProvider provider, Object[] arguments) +99
   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSourceFactory`1.ExecuteKeyQuery(Object[] keyValues) +402
   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute(Object instance) +888
   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSource.GetEnumerator() +51
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load() +107
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.GetEnumerator() +13
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +4
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\prc0092\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LockApp\LockApp\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:16
```

### Different things I tried

**Double locking**

Doesn't help

```
    private static object ThisLock = new object();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["c"] == null)
        {
            lock (ThisLock)
            {
                if (HttpRuntime.Cache["c"] == null)
                {
```

**Loading child data upfront**

Works, but requires constant maintenance as not all children should be loaded upfront, plus see next note

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Master>(b => b.Details);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

**Locking the master object while trying to access its children**

Again, requires maintenance as all **initial** places where child is accessed need to be found - we are struggling with this as there are different entry paths into the site

```
    @foreach(var m in ViewBag.Data){
        @m.Id<nbsp></nbsp>
        lock (m){
            foreach(var d in m.Details){
                @d.Id<nbsp></nbsp>
            }
        }
        <br />
    }
```

**Switching to entity framework**

This seems to still have (sometimes - much better than linq-sql) the "open connection" issue at certain number of parallel requests (50+ on core i7) - it does go away after a while as I mentioned and I haven't seen data corruption yet.

We may end up switching to EF completely as this seems to be the only viable path - assuming data corruption doesn't show up - that is to be tested on my actual project.

I am not optimistic though, as EF data context is not thread safe either, and I think the EF data objects carry their context with them.  **This is probably the only question that I don't have answer to yet.**

### Theories on why it's broken

It looks like storing LINQ-SQL object in http cache carries the data context with it. When this context is later used by multiple threads to access children, there is some type of concurrency issue that manifests itself in either temporary connectivity issue or complete data corruption of the child object. As there's no way to disconnect/reconnect the context from the LINQ object, it looks like the only suggestion is not to cache LINQ objects that need lazy-loading of their children - a substantial number of google searches I did does not seem to give you that advice, in fact sometimes it's opposite.

I have uploaded the complete project (for Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012)

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8CQRA9dD8POb3U5RGtCV3BMeU0/edit?usp=sharing
and a simple JMeter script that will hit your local machine with parallel requests:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8CQRA9dD8POd1VYdGRDMEFQbEU/edit?usp=sharing

to test, start the site and run the test - then touch the web.config on the site

Comment: Are you doing any of this inside of a static function? I was working with The Entity Framework and lambdas/linq, using a Singleton design pattern (The object is instantiated once and remains in memory until the application ends) and I came across some concurrency issues. Just a thought.

Comment: As I mentioned, this was cached in application cache, so effectively same thing as static (Application[] is a singleton)

Answer (score 0):

```
LockApp.Models.DBDataContext db = new Models.DBDataContext();

var master = db.Masters.ToList();
```

You should have a call to `db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false` in between these two calls. Otherwise all of the objects will be tracked by the datacontext so that changes can be written back into the database. Since you're caching these objects to be read by multiple threads, you do not want this. (It's also more expensive even in single-threaded cases to track objects you won't change, so worth doing in other places).

Also, use `LoadWith` to eagerly load any properties you might want to access of these cached entities, so they are all loaded on the initial caching thread, rather than with (potentially mulitple) threads that try to access them.

Comment: As I mentioned, the LoadWith was not feasible, since this required maintenance of entrance paths to the site.

Do you think ObjectTracking would have affected this though? 

I think in the new .net world we have to look at this by reading LINQ source.

Comment: Object tracking would certainly have affected it, though whether so much that disabling it would be enough to help is another question. If LoadWith isn't feasible, then be sure to not access the related properties directly, but to do so from a new query. Otherwise you're treating objects you want to be "dead" in the cache as "live" reflections of a database they're a cached record of.